# Cannot access Webservice client side using Jquery JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, web

I cannot access a Webservice through jquery and I cannot find the problem, I have checked everything but nothing seems to work.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function obtenerMunicipios() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/ObtenerMunicipios",
        data: { sEstado: "info" },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
        error: function (response) { alert("Error"); }
    });
}
```

This is called when a DropDownList changes, I have tested the WebMethod inside the web service and it works fine, it returns an ArrayList by the way, I already put the [ScriptService] and [WebMethod] respectively. It always tells me there is an error.

Visual Studio puts the code file in App_Code but the asmx file in root I don't know if that is a problem but I don't think so because I can access the webmethod server side.

The result always shows me the error alert, and if I put a breakpoint in the WebMethod it never arrives there so I think it is a problem with the URL.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for a return error
change your "error:" to this

```
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
```

and you can see much more in Firebug or Fiddler or IE9 Developer tools

Also you can create webmetod on your page, server side something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

On client change this

```
url: "PageName.aspx/GetDate"
```

Look at Dave page for example:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, check out what is being sent back via fiddler.  My guess is its sending 
back what ever it likes.

You'll need to specify what your request will accept by using the [beforeSend event](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
function obtenerMunicipios() 
{ 
     $.ajax({ 
              type: "POST", 
              url: "WebService.asmx/ObtenerMunicipios", 
              data: { sEstado: "info" }, 
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
              success: function (response) { alert(response.d); }, 
              error: function (response) { alert("Error"); },
              //This is the line you're looking for I think.
              beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept",
                                                              "application/json"); } 
         }); 
}
```